# SQL like clause difference between '%word-c%' and '%word-%'

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have the follwing query:

```
SELECT Url FROM Table n WHERE Url LIKE '%sipse.com/milenio/yucatan-%'
```

Which returns the following result set:

```
> http://sipse.com/milenio/yucatan-estados-
> http://sipse.com/milenio/yucatan-transpor
> http://sipse.com/milenio/yucatan-choferes 
> http://sipse.com/milenio/yucatan-congreso-pleno
```

But if I add a 'c' to the like parameter:

```
SELECT Url FROM Table n WHERE Url LIKE '%sipse.com/milenio/yucatan-c%'
```

The result set changes to only the next row:

```
> http://sipse.com/milenio/yucatan-congreso-pleno
```

Which is very strange to me because it should return:

```
> http://sipse.com/milenio/yucatan-choferes 
> http://sipse.com/milenio/yucatan-congreso-pleno
```

Does anyone have any idea about the reason of this behavior?

The collation of the Table is: Traditional_Spanish_CI_AS in SQL Server 2008

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since it is traditional Spanish we have the letter ch (Che)  (a, b, c, ch, d...). Take a look: http://www.olcot.co.uk/sql-blogs/revised-difference-between-collation-sql_latin1_general_cp1_ci_as-and-latin1_general_ci_as